# Filtrado de un json con objeto en mat-table angular

Tags: json, angular, filtro, angular-material, mat-table

Buen día y saludos a todos. Tengo un mat-table en angular donde muestro información recibida de un json, similar a esto:

```
[
 {
    Id: "1",
    Nombre: "Leonel",
    Serie: "75603",
    Modulo: {
      Entrada: "Optimizar",
      Salida: "Descargar"
    }
 },
 {
    Id: "2",
    Nombre: "Jennifer",
    Serie: "84219",
    Modulo: {
      Entrada: "Renovar",
      Salida: "Expedir"
    }
 }
]
```

El problema surge cuando uso el filtro de búsqueda, que funciona solo cuando agrego en la tabla las columnas: Id, Nombre y Serie. Si agrego las columnas Entrada y Salida me muestra la información pero el filtro ya no me funciona y en consola se genera el siguiente error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
  at eval (VM7878 table-basic-example.ts:51)
  at Array.some (<anonymous>)
  at MatTableDataSource.listData.filterPredicate (VM7878 table-basic-example.ts:48)
  at eval (table-data-source.ts:221)
  at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
  at MatTableDataSource._filterData (table-data-source.ts:221)
  at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (table-data-source.ts:199)
  at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:81)
  at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:102)
  at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.ts:247)
```

Tengo el código ya realizado en: [https://stackblitz.com/demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bh67u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es por que tienes un objeto anidado, entonces tienes que buscar en `"Modulo.Entrada"` pero para hacer esto, es necesario que hagas los siguientes cambios.

Cambia el nombre de tus columnas en `displayedColumns` delimitando las propiedades anidadas con un punto.

```
  displayedColumns: any[] = [
    "Id",
    "Nombre",
    "Serie",
    "Modulo.Entrada",
    "Modulo.Salida",
    "actions"
  ];
```

Así mismo debemos actualizar el html.

```
           <ng-container matColumnDef="Modulo.Entrada">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Entrada</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Modulo.Entrada}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Modulo.Salida">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Salida</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Modulo.Salida}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

Ahora falta buscar la propiedad correcta, esto lo logramos separando las propiedades mediante un split en el string de `displayedColumns`.

```
  getValueFrom(data: any, column: string) {
    if (column.includes(".")) {
      const nested = column.split(".");
      return nested.reduce((prev, current) => {
        return prev[current];
      }, data);
    }
    return data[column];
  }
```

Al final solo invocamos la función.

```
    this.listData.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      return this.displayedColumns.some(ele => {
        return (
          ele != "actions" &&
          this.getValueFrom(data, ele)
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(filter) != -1
        );
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola jefferson otra forma a la de oscar puede ser descomentar todo lo que tienes y solo en la función de filtrar.

```
 this.listData.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      const dataStr = JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase();
      return dataStr.indexOf(filter) != -1;
 };
```

Y ya funciona sin errores, como puedes ver convertirmos el json a una cadena de texto y con el indexOf buscamos el filtro que es mandado y realizamos la operación.

Espero te sirva saludos :)